# Using Ruby at the command line, how to take a specific column that loop through each one

Tags: ruby, enumeration

I have a command line script that returns something like:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
a    b    c    d    e
a1   b2   c2   d2   e2
a3   b3   c3   d3   e3
..
..
.
```

Now I want to take the values from col3, and then call another command line script for each row in column 3.

I know ruby has a system("..") function that will run a script in console.

My command line script is very similiar to calling something like:

```
system("ls -l")
```

Now how could I capture column#3, and iterate over each value and fire off another script passing the value from col#3 as a parameter?

Comment: "Rows of values for each column", "each row in column 3", "rows of information with 9 columns", "column#3, and iterate over each value": These expressions are hard to understand.

Comment: sawa I've updated it, your right the wording was confusing, hope this is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IO.popen('ls -l').lines.map(&:split)[1..-1].transpose[2].each do |e|
  puts '>>' + e + '<<'
end
```

I should warn you that if you take this to the obvious next step and construct a call to "system" or even `popen` within the block, you will be creating a code injection risk. In this specific case, where only alphanumeric results are expected for the file's owner, simply filtering for only those characters should be good enough.

Comment: I'm running this locally, and all input is trusted.

Comment: Sure, I suspected as much. I would rather have not said anything but posting a simple explanation here on SO sometimes provokes a security witch-hunt as if the *Gold Codes* themselves were at risk, so I always have to say the caveat. I should keep it ready to go and just paste it in. To be fair to the inquisitors, some answers *are* visited a lot over the years and we do have to consider what future visitors will see...

Comment: that's very thoughtful of you to the interwebs :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just have somehing like

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
cols, take_col = ARGV[0],ARGV[1]
puts $stdin.read.split.drop(cols).select.with_index{|x, i| i % cols == take_col - 1}
```

in a file, say, named `take-col`, and use it with pipe, like

```
$ ls-like-cmd | take-col 5 3 | next-cmd
```